# Drop rows of a Pandas dataframe if the value of range columns 0

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

**Dataframe:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['NA','W','Q','M'], 'b':[0,0,4,2], 'c':[0,12,0,2], 'd':[22, 3, 34, 12], 'e':[0,0,3,6], 'f':[0,2,0,0], 'h':[0,1,1,0] })
df
    a   b   c   d   e   f   h
0   NA  0   0   22  0   0   0
1   W   0   12  3   0   2   1
2   Q   4   0   34  3   0   1
3   M   2   2   12  6   0   0
```

I want to drop the entire row if the value of column `b` and all columns   `e` contain 0

Basically I want to get something like this

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   h
1   W   0   12  3   0   2   1
2   Q   4   0   34  3   0   1
3   M   2   2   12  6   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want test from `e` to end columns and `b` columns added by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecing, test for not equal by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and then if aby values match (it means no all `0`) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.loc[:, 'e':].assign(b = df['b']).ne(0).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
   a  b   c   d  e  f  h
1  W  0  12   3  0  2  1
2  Q  4   0  34  3  0  1
3  M  2   2  12  6  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want column ``b `` and range ``e: to_end_end``

Comment: This is exactly what I need and it works perfectly with the latest version od pandas but it does not work for ``0.17``.  am running ``0.17`` on prod

Comment: @Ayalew - For oldier pandas versions use `df = df[df.loc[:, 'e':].join(df['b']).ne(0).any(axis=1)]`